# Proposal Function For Variables That Sum To 1 (Dirichlet Prior)

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings, dirichlet-distribution

Recently I've been trying to use MCMC to infer a set of 50 random variables (species frequencies) that sum to 1 with the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. However, the algorithm is not working well because of a poor proposal function. So far I've tried two proposals that theoretically should cover the range of the prior: (1) Add X ~ Uniform(0, 0.02) to each variable, and divide by the resulting sum of all the variables, and (2) Same as above except X ~ log-normal.

For example, if I had 4 random variables that were .25,.25,.25,.25, I might have added X ~ Uniform(0,0.02) to each of them, to get .26,.27,.27,.26, and then divided by the sum 1.06 to get .245, .255,.255,.245

But for metropolis-Hastings, you have to correct for the proposal probability, and the issue is that these proposal functions are not very reversible. That is, most proposed steps cannot be reversed, so the algorithm will never select them. For a reasonable proposal step-size, only ~1% of proposals are even theoretically reversible. Are there any known proposal functions that work well with these types of variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not use a dirichlet proposal?

Comment: eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Gamma_distribution

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.  I wasn't planning to because the Dirichlet proposal can't "tune" the variance on each variable, so the distance between a proposal and the distribution that proposed it is massive.  Especially when the range of the 50 variables is generally within .001-0.2, the Dirichlet keeps proposing values like 1E-82 which will make sampling from the joint Markov Chain very hard.

Comment: @alanocallaghan I tried it, unfortunately the Dirichlet proposal is even more irreversible.  Even something simple, like if Q  ~ dirichlet(concentration = (.2,.2,.2,.2,.2)), the ratio of the forward vs reverse proposal is on the order of 10^-13. Code being q = rdirichlet(1,rep(.2,5)), ratio = ddirichlet(rep(.2,5), q)/ddirichlet(q, rep(.2,5))

Comment: If dimension is an issue, you can resort to Gibbs sampling by changing only 2 (or 3, 4, ...) components at once and keeping the others constant.

Comment: Fair enough, sampling from a dirichlet is pretty challenging. Have you tried to use Stan for this model? I have found it mixes pretty well with Dirichlet/Dirichlet-multinomial models, at least compared to MH

Comment: Sure I can try Stan, thanks for tip. Ok so far two proposal functions, either Dirichlet proposal or adding X ~ Uniform to each variable and dividing by their sum (so that they add to 1; and probability for MCMC can be obtained through a variation of Irwin-Hall distribution).  I wonder if I could do something similar to Dirichlet, except instead of drawing from Gamma Distribution, I could draw from something else with less variance.

Comment: What about logistic-normal?